# Function describing a cup with certain diameter, height and radius

Tags: geometry, functions

I'm looking for a mathematical expression that describes an axially symmetric cup with a flange. The cup is defined by the diameter d, the height h, the flange diameter D and the radius r.

[image]

I thought about the arctan function, but I have to specify the radius. If possible, the other sectors should be linear (horizontal/vertical).

I used the signum function, but I have no idea how to add the radii:

(e.g. h = 5; D = 20; d = 10; r = 1;)

x = linspace(0,D/2);

**y = (h/2) * sign(x - d/2) + h/2;**

Comment: There are different possible answers and it would be helpful to tell us why you want such a function.

Comment: I need pairs of values for another calculation. At the moment, I create the values programmatically by combining the 5 segments' values. I am curious if it could be done with a single function.

Comment: Due to the "piecewise" nature of your shape (segment/arc/segment/arc/segment), it is pretty difficult and very artificial to derive a single equation. In addition, a function is unable to represent a vertical line.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I think I stick with my segment-wise solution. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you want to achieve (because your shape has discontinuities), but qualitatively satisfying:

$$x=\ln(e^{t-10}+1)-\ln(e^t+1)+t+10,\\
y=\ln(e^t+1)-\ln(e^{t-10}+1).$$

[image]

You can adjust the overall dimensions by introducing scaling parameters, but you won't get true circles.